# UrlGenerationError on section 5.12 of Rails Guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm following the Getting Started tutorial for Rails 4.0.0 located here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#updating-posts

When I try to navigate from the main page (localhost) to localhost/posts, I am getting this error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Posts#index
Showing C:/RailsInstaller/blog/app/views/posts/index.html.erb where line #16 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:id]
Extracted source (around line #16):

13   <tr>
14     <td><%= post.title %></td>
15     <td><%= post.text %></td>
16     <td><%= link_to 'Show', post_path %></td>
17     <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
18   </tr>
19 <% end %>
```

Additionally, when I try to edit a post, I receive a SyntaxError in my edit.html.erb file:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/blog/app/views/posts/edit.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
';@output_buffer.append=  form_for :post, url: post_path(@post.id) },
                                                                    ^
C:/RailsInstaller/blog/app/views/posts/edit.html.erb:32: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end
```

Specifically, with this line:

```
<%= form_for :post, url: post_path(@post.id) },
  method: :patch do |f| %>
```

This my first attempt at learning Rails, so I'm having a difficult time understanding where to even begin to look when I'm getting these errors. Here are some relevant files:

#### posts_controller.rb:

class PostsController < ApplicationController

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end

def new
  @post = Post.new
end

def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))

  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

#### edit.html.rb:

```
<h1>Editing post</h1>

<%= form_for :post, url: post_path(@post.id) },
method: :patch do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
  <div id="errorExplanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this post from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>
```

<%= f.submit %>

#### routes:rb:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  root to: "welcome#index"
end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it says the error is caused by this line

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', post_path %></td>
```

It should be

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
```

or

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', post_path(post) %></td>
```

Comment: And the other one is just a stray `}` after `post_path(@post.id)`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Any idea why that code was included in the guide then? I copied it verbatim from the site.

Comment: @brimtown, You're right. I check the guide. However I'm not up to rails 4 yet. I know prior to rails 4, that's a wrong expression. So it  could be the new rails way, or it could be a typo. But since you tried the example and got an error, it's most likely their typo.

Comment: @Henry, I tried it on Rails 4 and I got the same problem. So it looks like it's a typo!