# undefined method 'id' - Section 5.12 Updating Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I'm following the Getting Started tutorial for Rails 4.0.0, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#updating-posts, and was having the same problem as the user who asked this question, [UrlGenerationError on section 5.12 of Rails Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480518/urlgenerationerror-on-section-5-12-of-rails-guide).  However, after fixing the issue he had with post_path and removing the '}' that was throwing an error, I now get an undefined method 'id' error message when I try to edit a post.  I've been searching stackoverflow and google for a people with similar problems but have not been able to find a solution.  Any help is much appreciated.

Below is my Posts controller and my edit.html.erb file

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def new
    @post = Post.new
end 

def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  if @post.save
    redirect_to action: :show, id: @post.id
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def show 
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end 

def index 
  @posts = Post.all
end 

private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end 

def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
end
```

**edit.html.erb:**

```
    <h1>Editing post</h1>

<%= form_for :post, url: post_path(@post.id) ,
method: :patch do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
  <div id="errorExplanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this post from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

Comment: can you point out the line that this error is pointing to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with moving You `edit` and `update` methods out of the private scope! And point to the line the error is appearing.

Comment: Well I feel dumb.  Didn't realize 'private' worked liked that.  Thanks!